# Limit Checkboxes from getting checked when two separate drop-down options are selected?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, dom, addeventlistener

I'm trying to limit the checkbox options when a specific combination of values is selected.

I have a checkgroup with the name of `toneCapArray` that I want to limit the checkboxes when `value="bp"` and `value="master-tone"` are selected. These values are specified in the last two select boxes.

I'm running into a roadblock as I've only been learning JS for a few months. I can't get the function to run when those two values are selected.

When the `checkboxlimit(toneCapArray, 1);` function runs directly under the function definition, it works.

However, when I call the function by seeing if both are true:  `(item.value === "bp" && item.value === "master-tone")`  it does not work, and I get no errors or anything to help debug it.

### To reproduce:

1. Uncomment line 28 of the fiddle and try to select 3 checkboxes.
2. Comment line 28 and uncomment line 37
3. Select  Master Tone & Blender Pot in select boxes 3 & 4, and try to check 3 checkboxes again.

### Extra questions:

1. I have an event listener on 8 select boxes, but I only need the event listener to listen to two. Is it okay to listen to multiple select boxes and listen for the value?
2. I'm planning on expanding this to run the same function but with different arguments when a separate Radio button is selected, but I figured I'd start here. I'd like this to be scalable.

### FIDDLE:

[JS FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/sackadelic/o8hz9dw7/5/)

```js
function masterCheckboxLimit() {
  //set up the locations:

  const toneCapArray = document.getElementsByName("addon-3987-tone-cap-2[]");
  var select = document.querySelectorAll("select");

  //limit the checkboxes:

  function checkboxlimit(checkgroup, limit) {
    for (var i = 0; i < checkgroup.length; i++) {
      checkgroup[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
        var checkedcount = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < checkgroup.length; i++) {
          checkedcount += checkgroup[i].checked ? 1 : 0;
          if (checkedcount > limit) {
            window.alert("You can only select a maximum of " + limit + " tone caps");
            this.checked = false;
          }
        }
      });
    }
  }


  //select the select boxes and add a change event listener

  select.forEach((item) => {
    item.addEventListener("change", (e) => {

      if (document.getElementsByName("pa_tone-pot-1")[0].value === "master-tone" && document.getElementsByName("pa_tp-2")[0].value === "bp"){
    checkboxlimit(toneCapArray, 1); //I want this function to run when both are true above
    });
  });
}
masterCheckboxLimit();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Product Options:</h1>
    <p>
      <select name="pickup_location" id="" label="">
        <option value="">Select an Option</option>
        <option value="complete_set">Complete Set</option>
        <option value="neck">Neck</option>
        <option value="bridge">Bridge</option>
      </select>
    </p>

    <p>
      <select name="pickup_color" id="" label="">
        <option value="">Select an Option</option>
        <option value="black">Black</option>
        <option value="white">White</option>
      </select>
    </p>

    <p>
      <select name="tone_pot_1" id="" label="">
        <option value="">Select an Option</option>
        <option value="neck_middle_tone">Neck and Middle Tone</option>
        <option value="master-tone">Master Tone</option>
      </select>
    </p>
    <p>
      <select name="tone_pot_2" id="" label="">
        <option value="">Select an Option</option>
        <option value="bp">Blender Pot</option>
        <option value="bridge-tone">Bridge Tone</option>
      </select>
    </p>

    <h2>Add Ons:</h2>

    <p><input type="checkbox" id="1" name="addon-3987-tone-cap-2[]" value="Cap 1" label="Cap 1" /><label for="1">Tone Cap 1</label></p>
    <p><input type="checkbox" id="2" name="addon-3987-tone-cap-2[]" value="Cap 2" label="Cap 2" /><label for="2">Tone Cap 2</label></p>
    <p><input type="checkbox" id="3" name="addon-3987-tone-cap-2[]" value="Cap 3" label="Cap 3" /><label for="3">Tone Cap 3</label></p>
  </body>

</html>
```

Is there anything glaring in my code?

Comment: I see 2 problems in your code

Comment: Note that `checkboxlimit` is *adding* an event listener every time it is called, but never removing any, so when a checkgroup is clicked, it will run each and every event listener that has ever been added since the page was loaded. That's usually a Bad Thing (tm).

Comment: Instead of `item.value === "bp"` you likely want `document.getElementsByName('tone_pot_2')[0].value === "bp"`, since that select is the only one with that value. Likewise with the other value.

Comment: Thanks for this. I changed them on my code. How would you manipulate the code to remove the event listener?

Comment: is this ever possible? item.value === "bp" && item.value === "master-tone"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see 2 problems in your code

### 1 - That will be always **false** so it won't ever enter the if block.

```js
if (item.value === "bp" && item.value === "master-tone")
```

Since `"bp" !== "master-tone"` item.value cannot be equal both (unless you have a hacky getter there)

### 2 - You are looking for a value **bp** but that value is not in the HTML code

That might be playing a role as well since you are looking for something that does not exist.

UPDATE:

I think the following runnable snippet will do what you want, check it out.

```js
function masterCheckboxLimit() {
  const tone_pot_1 = document.querySelector('#tone_pot_1')
  const tone_pot_2 = document.querySelector('#tone_pot_2')
  const checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]')

  let maxNumberOfMarkedCheckBoxesAllowed = 3
  let curNumberOfMarkedCheckBoxesAllowed = 0

  function selectsOnChangeEvent(e) {
    if (tone_pot_1.value === 'master-tone' && tone_pot_2.value === 'bp') {
      maxNumberOfMarkedCheckBoxesAllowed = 1
      if (curNumberOfMarkedCheckBoxesAllowed > maxNumberOfMarkedCheckBoxesAllowed) {
        checkboxes.forEach(checkbox => {
          checkbox.checked = false
        })
        curNumberOfMarkedCheckBoxesAllowed = 0
        alert(`If you have master-tone and bp you can only check 1 box. Please make your selection again`)
      }
    } else {
      maxNumberOfMarkedCheckBoxesAllowed = 3
    }
  }

  function checkBoxOnClickEvent(e) {
    const number = this.checked ? 1 : -1

    if (curNumberOfMarkedCheckBoxesAllowed + number > maxNumberOfMarkedCheckBoxesAllowed) {
      alert('Nope')
      return e.preventDefault()
    }

    curNumberOfMarkedCheckBoxesAllowed += number

    console.log({
      number,
      curNumberOfMarkedCheckBoxesAllowed,
      maxNumberOfMarkedCheckBoxesAllowed
    })
  }

  [tone_pot_1, tone_pot_2].forEach((checkbox) => {
    checkbox.addEventListener('change', selectsOnChangeEvent)
  })


  checkboxes.forEach((checkbox) => {
    checkbox.addEventListener('click', checkBoxOnClickEvent)
  })
}

masterCheckboxLimit();
```

```css
label { cursor: pointer; }
#selects, #checkboxes { float: left }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="selects">
    <h1>Product Options:</h1>
    <p>
      <select name="pickup_location" id="pickup_location" label="">
        <option value="">Select an Option</option>
        <option value="complete_set">Complete Set</option>
        <option value="neck">Neck</option>
        <option value="bridge">Bridge</option>
      </select>
    </p>

    <p>
      <select name="pickup_color" id="pickup_color" label="">
        <option value="">Select an Option</option>
        <option value="black">Black</option>
        <option value="white">White</option>
      </select>
    </p>

    <p>
      <select name="tone_pot_1" id="tone_pot_1" label="">
        <option value="">Select an Option</option>
        <option value="neck_middle_tone">Neck and Middle Tone</option>
        <option value="master-tone">Master Tone</option>
      </select>
    </p>
    <p>
      <select name="tone_pot_2" id="tone_pot_2" label="">
        <option value="">Select an Option</option>
        <option value="bp">Blender Pot</option>
        <option value="bridge-tone">Bridge Tone</option>
      </select>
    </p>
  </div>
  <div id="checkboxes">
    <h2>Add Ons:</h2>
    <p><input type="checkbox" id="1" name="addon-3987-tone-cap-2[]" value="Cap 1" label="Cap 1" /><label for="1">Tone Cap 1</label></p>
    <p><input type="checkbox" id="2" name="addon-3987-tone-cap-2[]" value="Cap 2" label="Cap 2" /><label for="2">Tone Cap 2</label></p>
    <p><input type="checkbox" id="3" name="addon-3987-tone-cap-2[]" value="Cap 3" label="Cap 3" /><label for="3">Tone Cap 3</label></p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The `bp` is in select box 4. `<option value="bp">Blender Pot</option>`

Comment: Hey @Mestre San, how would you re-write this statement so both values would be true?

Comment: @Sackadelic, he's done it in his code for you `if (tone_pot_1.value === 'master-tone' && tone_pot_2.value === 'bp') `.  One of the issues with your original code was that the `item` variable in your `select.forEach` loop could never possibly be two different values.  Each iteration recreates the variable anew, because it essentially runs 4 different functions, one for each select created when you run `var select = document.querySelectorAll("select");`  Keep figuring out how closures and scope work in js and you'll get it:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures

Comment: Thanks so much, @Mestre San. I was able to do it a different way, but your tip helped me accomplish it! I was stuck on that point. Thanks again!